# How does a Muslim regain taharah after using a western style toilet?

Tags: taharah

Compared to indian style toilets, western toilets are comfortable but cleanliness-wise, worst because using it involves the resting of thighs on the commode which is mostly unclean.

Though after use, taharah can be regained by washing the thighs, it is not practical to do it with pants (izaars or bottoms) on and hence ghusl could be preferred.

Performing ghusl after use is also not practical when he is outside home (trains, flights, etc.). **How then would a Muslim use the western toilets and regain taharah without ghusl?**

This question is very important because these days all toilets in trains, flights and hotels are being westernised.

Comment: I wonder why Muslims make commode toilets, when they build homes etc.

Comment: The short answer is by doing proper istinja'! I can't really see why this needs a specified answer!

Answer (score 10):

1. Take a toilet paper, make it slightly wet by putting some soap or disinfect on it.
2. Clean the toilet seat with the wet toilet paper.
3. Discard the toilet paper in the bin.
4. Finally clean the seat with a dry toilet paper again.
5. Use the seat which is now clean and also germ free.

Comment: To make this more universal, you may want to change step 3 to "Discard the toilet paper into the trash bin" (so as to avoid clogging the toilet in case the flush is weak).

Answer (score 0):

Use a bottle (such as your medium or small size fruit juice bottle or even  a plastic glass of water) and take water with you to the wash room. You can do taharah using that water in the bottle. Or there are some bottle of water that have a hole at top and water comes our like a jet of water (Those are found in hospitals too). Getting taharah might be easier using those bottles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toilet shower to wash the toilet seat and sit on it.
Obviously evry commode comes with a shower  ?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the ways to dealt with dirty public toilets:

- Wash the seat with the bidet or wipe it with a wet paper towel as already covered in another answer.
- Lift the seat and sit on the porcelain base. It is sometimes clean or at least easier to clean yourself. Although it is less comfortable.
- Place a layer of toilet paper on the seat so there is a barrier between it and your skin.
- Wash your thighs. Take off your trousers beforehand if they make it inconvenient. Hang them to a door if a hook is available otherwise hang them around yourself by tying the legs around your neck.