# Islamic way of visiting the toilet

Tags: taharah

I would like to know if there are any Hadith that recommend what kind of toilets one must use. Such as Western toilets (Water closet) or Squat toilets.

Comment: Related: [How does a muslim regain taharah after using western style toilets?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1516/59)

Answer (score 5):

A squat toilet would be the one recommended based on a sole (weak) riwayah from al-Sunan al-Kubra of al-Bayhaqi.

(حديث مرفوع) وَأَنْبَأَنِي أَبُو عَبْدِ اللَّهِ الْحَافِظُ إِجَازَةً ، ثنا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ إِسْحَاقَ الْفَقِيهُ ، أنا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ ، ثنا عَمْرُو بْنُ عَلِيٍّ ، ثنا أَبُو عَاصِمٍ ، عَنْ رَبِيعَةَ ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ ، عَنْ رَجُلٍ مِنْ بَنِي مُدْلِجٍ ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ ، قَالَ : قَدِمَ عَلَيْنَا سُرَاقَةُ بْنُ جُعْشُمٍ ، فَقَالَ 5 : عَلَّمَنَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ : " إِذَا دَخَلَ أَحَدُنَا الْخَلاءَ أَنْ يَعْتَمِدَ الْيسْرَى ، وَيَنْصِبَ الْيُمْنَى " .

From Suraqah b. Ju3shum, who said: The Messenger of Allah (saww) informed us to support (place weight on) the left foot and to leave the right one free (i.e. not support oneself with the right) whenever anyone of us entered the toilet.