# Praying with the urge to urinate

Tags: salat, wudu

Assalamu alaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu,

Is it makrooh or is it impermissible to pray when you have the urge to urinate. When I’m at school, sometimes I need to go to the toilet but I take Wudu and pray because the toilets might be unclean. Is this wrong? Please let me know.

Jazakallah khair.

Comment: Why might the toilets be unclean? What do you actually mean by "unclean"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two links will help you understand better
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/8603/ruling-on-praying-whilst-resisting-the-urge-to-urinate-or-defecate
https://islamqa.org/hanafi/muftionline/91074

Both this links has one statement in common - it is makhrooh or disliked to start  prayer in state of urgency..yes, in the first link they does say that " it is not permissible " but then they say if somebody does this his/her prayer is "not invalid" but it "lacks perfection" i.e. imperfect " ..however if you feel the urge after starting the salah(not before) you can continue the prayer(as mentioned in the 1st link) and this will not make your salah makhrooh..
There comes a question that "how much urgency" makes salah makhrooh is described in 2nd link as - " It is makrooh to perform salaah when there is a need. Need means that you have the urge to relieve yourself. A slight feeling that comes up now and then is not what is referred to though it will be better to perform the salaah when this feeling also has subsided entirely."..
But best thing to do is to get rid off urgency to urinate..
As with using "Western-style" toilets that might be "unclean" you can use the techniques(please go through them) mentioned in the following link and hopefully will be able to use those toilets even in your school without having the the fear of impurity..
[How does a Muslim regain taharah after using a western style toilet?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1516/how-does-a-muslim-regain-taharah-after-using-a-western-style-toilet)
 and Allah knows the best